# Poisson regression with autocorrelated residuals

Tags: autocorrelation, residuals, poisson-regression, segmented-regression, neweywest

i am running a Poisson segmented regression on monthly cases following the classic format by Wagner:

Wagner AK, Soumerai SB, Zhang F, Ross-Degnan D. Segmented regression analysis of interrupted time series studies in medication use research. J Clin Pharm Ther. 2002 Aug;27(4):299-309. doi: 10.1046/j.1365-2710.2002.00430.x. PMID: 12174032.

The model is of the form:

log(cases) ~ b1 * time + b2 * intervention + b3 * time_after_intervention + offset(log(population))

In the model i have adjusted for seasonality including a combination of sin-cos terms.

When i check for residual autocorrelation (by checking the autocorrelation graph - acf(resid(model)) in R) i see that the first two lags are significant.

What i have done to correct for this is add the terms lag(cases,1) and lag(cases,2) in the model in which case the autocorrelation problem seems to be solved. There is finally overdispersion so a quasipoisson model is preferred.

My question is this: Is this the right approach? It seems more natural to add lag(log(cases),1) and lag(log(cases),2) instead, should that be preferred? The beta estimates are a bit different depending on what is used.

Another suggested way to correct for this is to adjust the standard errors using the Newey-West method as mentioned here:

Bottomley, Christian, Scott, J. Anthony G. and Isham, Valerie. "Analysing Interrupted Time Series with a Control" Epidemiologic Methods, vol. 8, no. 1, 2019, pp. 20180010. https://doi.org/10.1515/em-2018-0010

In this way we seem to adjust for both overdispersion and autocorrelation at once. Is this a better approach?

I would really appreciate any input on this and grateful if it can be combined with some literature suggestions.

Comment: For each model I suggest making a scatter plot of the data with the model fit overlaid to see which one looks better.  You could also see which model has a smaller AIC.  You may also decide based on interpretation of the coefficients.  Is there an additive relationship between log(mu) and lag case?  Is there an additive relationship between log(mu) and log(lag case)?